# Python, SQLAlchemy pass parameters in connection.execute

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, parameter-passing

I am using SQLAlchemy connection.execute(sql) to transform select results to array of maps. Have following code

```
def __sql_to_data(sql):
    result = []
    connection = engine.connect()
    try:
        rows = connection.execute(sql)
        for row in rows:
            result_row = {}
            for col in row.keys():
                result_row[str(col)] = str(row[col])
            result.append(result_row)
    finally:
        connection.close()
    return result
```

and e.g.

```
__sql_to_data(sql_get_scan_candidate)
```

gives me nice data structure (Of course I am using this for small data sets).
But in order to add parameter to sql I am currently using format e.g.

```
return __sql_to_data(sql_get_profile.format(user_id))
```

**Question**
How to modify procedure to make possible something like

```
return __sql_to_data(sql_get_profile,user_id)
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[The tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) gives a pretty good example for this:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import text
>>> s = text(
...     "SELECT users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title "
...         "FROM users, addresses "
...         "WHERE users.id = addresses.user_id "
...         "AND users.name BETWEEN :x AND :y "
...         "AND (addresses.email_address LIKE :e1 "
...             "OR addresses.email_address LIKE :e2)")
SQL>>> conn.execute(s, {"x": "m", "y": "z", "e1": "%@aol.com", "e2": "%@msn.com"}).fetchall() 
[(u'Wendy Williams, wendy@aol.com',)]
```

First, take your SQL string and pass it to [sqalchemy.sql.text()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text). This isn't necessary, but probably a good idea...

> The advantages text() provides over a plain string are backend-neutral
> support for bind parameters, per-statement execution options, as well
> as bind parameter and result-column typing behavior, allowing
> SQLAlchemy type constructs to play a role when executing a statement
> that is specified literally.

Note that even if you didn't use `text()`, you should NEVER just use `sql.format(...)`. This leads to greater risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Next, you can specify the actual arguments using keyword parameters to the [execute()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) function you've already been using.

Now, in your example, you have a function that wraps the execute functionality. So, if you want to use this for multiple queries, you'll need to make the parameters able to receive your arguments. You could do this pretty simple as a dictionary:

```
def _sql_to_data(sql, values):
    ...
    conn.execute(sql, values)
```

`values` would be a dictionary.You could then use your function like this...

```
sql = 'SELECT ...'
data = { 'user_id' : 3 }
results = _sql_to_data(sql, data)
```

Using keywords as your parameters is just one way of specifying the arguments to the `execute()` function. You can read [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) for that function for a few different ways.

Comment: Thank you, my bad, by some reason I was not able to find this in doc. My only one excuse SQLAlchemy doc is somewhat fragmented with emphasis  on ORM.

Comment: One more question - how fetchAll() and then itterating in results data structure relates to for row in rows in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: @Denis: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Perhaps you should create another StackOverflow question, and try to be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: `text` does not let you create a list of values which is a tremendous downside and often makes it unusable in many of my cases making format the only real way.

Comment: @stevenwade Format is never the real way, unleas you mean formatting the required placeholders for the list values, and SQLAlchemy even does it for you using [`bindparam(..., expanding=True)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding). On the other hand some DB-API drivers adapt arrays out of the box to suitable SQL.

Comment: I was spinning my wheels on this for awhile until I came across this post. Using python3.7 and the `text` method was indeed necessary. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Hi @MarkHildreth, I've tried your solution but I have the following error: `get_bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`. I'm trying to execute the following query: `query = sqlalchemy.sql.text("INSERT INTO public.migrations (name) VALUES (:name)")` and I have the following tupple object: `migrations = ({"name": "__init__.yaml"})`

Comment: In 2.0 style, values must be passed as a dict (or list of dicts); individual keyword arguments are no longer accepted.

Comment: 9 years later @MarkHildreth still answering my questions 

Comment: With the query being `text` one can also use the `params=` argument for `execute` and provide a dictionary.

Answer (score 14):

This is the latest way to bind params for session execute

```py
stmt = text("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE user_id = :x")
stmt = stmt.bindparams(x="1")
res = session.execute(stmt).all()
```