# Import json with missing keys into postgres with Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a question you guys might be able to answer.

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
[
{
        "address": "some address",
        "full_time_school": false,
        "name": "some name",
        "official_id": "722154",
        "school_type": "Grundschule",
        "school_type_entity": "Grundschule",
        "state": "BW"
    },
    {
        "address": "some other address",
        "name": "some other name",
        "official_id": "722190",
        "state": "BW"
    }
]
```

The point is that not every entry has all keys.

I have a flask-sqlalchemy model that looks like this:

```
class School(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "school"  # pragma: no cover

    address = db.Column(db.String)
    full_time_school = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    official_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    school_type = db.Column(db.String)
    school_type_entity = db.Column(db.String)
    state = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<name {self.name}"
```

And I have a python script to add the json entries into my postgresql database that looks like this:

```
from my_project import db
from my_project.models import School

import json
import os

# insert data
for filename in os.listdir("datamining"):
    if filename.endswith(".json"):

        file = open(os.path.join("datamining", filename))

        print(f"Add schools from {filename.strip('.json')}")

        data = json.load(file)

        cleaned_data = {school["official_id"]: school for school in data}.values()
        print(f"Adding {len(data)} schools to the database.")

        for school in cleaned_data:
            entry = School(
                    id=school["official_id"]
                )
            for key, value in school.items():
                entry.key = value
            
            db.session.add(entry)
            db.session.commit()
        file.close()

print("Added all schools!!!")
```

I don't know why but somehow every cell is NULL except the `official_id` field. How so and how can I fix that? I'm at the end of my wits right now. Every pointer or help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
What I found out so far is, that `entry.key` is not interpreted as `entry.state` for example, but actually creates a reference `entry.key = "BW"` for example. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

```py
entry.key = value
```

You are just writing your values over and over into the attribute 'key' within your `School` model. I'm actually surprised SQLAlchemy doesn't raise some kind of error here...
Just pass all your values into the constructor and you should be fine:

```py
school["id"] = school.pop("official_id")
entry = School(**school)
```

EDIT: It's "BW" because this happens to be the last value that is written into the attribute.

Comment: I just realized that `official_id` is a field in your database. I'm not familiar with Flask-SQLAlchemy and how to pass ids. I could imagine that 'id' is actually set by the database and updated in the session on a flush. Then you could omit the line where I pop school[`official_id`].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much easier and faster all in one go by [executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314342/python-sqlalchemy-pass-parameters-in-connection-execute) this native parameterized query passing the text contents of the JSON file as parameter `jsontext`:

```sql
insert into school 
 select * from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::school, :jsontext::jsonb);
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the above solution, but I will try your solution the next time I have to import json data :)