# How to pass parameters to SQL query using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, file-handling

I have a list of existing tables in database, I need to update existing tables with CSV files. So what I have done is:

1. I have created temp tables in database and I have inserted the
   values from CSV files to the temp tables in database.
2. Then I have made two lists, one list consists of existing tables and
   other list consists of temp table.
3. I created my temp tables with prefixed existing tables names ending
   with temp eg. tablenametemp, so that I can match with existing
   tables.
4. Once I found the match then I will update the existing tables with
   the temp tables with matching primary keys.
5. If the primary key already exists the I will update the existing
   records ELSE I will insert it as a new record to the table
6. Once all done temp tables are removed here is the code which I have
   done.

Here is my code:

```
for a in list_table:
    if a+'temp' in list_temp:
        pk = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
                                    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
                                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = ? 
                                    AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'  ''',a)


        pk_temp = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
                                    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = T.CONSTRAINT_NAME  
                                    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = ? 
                                    AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'  ''',a+"temp")
        col = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?  ''',a)
        col_temp = engine.execute('''
                                    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?  ''',a+"temp")
        query_params = { 'table' : str(a),
                         'table_temp' : str(a+'temp'),
                         'primary_key' : str(pk),
                         'primary_key_temp' : str(pk_temp),
                         'columns' : str(col),
                         'columns_temp' : str(col_temp),
                         'columns1': str(col),
                         'columns_temp2': str(col_temp)
        }

        sql_merge = text("""
        MERGE ? Target
        USING ? AS Source
        ON Source.? = Target.?
        /* new records ('right match') */
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
        INSERT (?)
        VALUES (Source.?)
        /* matching records ('inner match') */
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        Target.? = Source.?
        /* deprecated records ('left match') */
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
        DELETE
        ;
        """ )

        c = engine.execute(sql_merge, params = query_params)
        engine.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ? """, a+"temp")
```

I have tried passing parameters in this way and I  get an error like this

> COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0)

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: are you using SQLAlchemy? Different packages pass parameters to SQL statements with different syntaxes.

Comment: yes I'm using SQLAlchemy

Comment: There are quite a few ways to use SQLAlchemy and you may take a look at this link to see if it solves your questions...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314342/python-sqlalchemy-pass-parameters-in-connection-execute

Comment: This seems to be pretty much identical to your previous question? And the comment made on your last question still holds, you can't parameterise table or column names. For that you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: If i was good at Dynamic SQL , I could have done it, but I'm not.... i am new to this , help me out in this @DaleK

Comment: Dynamic SQL is a big topic, one you need to study some tutorials on.