# How to solve second order SQL injection attacks vulnerability?

Tags: python, pandas, security, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm facing a challenge while deploying a backed application built using `Python Flask`. The codegate scan is catching up some of the code integrated in the CI/CD process as potential vulnerabilities. Below are 2 types of vulnerabilities.

1. Second order `SQL` injection.
2. SQL injection

I'm using raw SQL queries to get the data from the DB in conjunction with `Flask SQLAlchemy` and `Pandas`.

Below is a sample code where codegate is pointing the issues for Second order `SQL` injection.

```
def get_user_data(user_id: str):
  query: str = USER_ID_QUERY.format(user_id=user_id)
  result = db.session.execute(query)
  result = result.fetchall()
  if len(result) < 1:
    raise Exception("User not Found")
  return result[0][0]
```

> Query

```
USER_ID_QUERY = """SELECT USER_ID FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = '{user_id}'"""
```

> Vulnerability description - Method get_user_data at line 236 of
> src\utils.py gets database data from the execute element. This
> element’s value then flows through the code without being properly
> sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in a database query in
> method check_access at line 50 of src\service.py. This may enable an
> `Second-Order SQL Injection attack`.

I have tried below solution after digging out the internet by still it is giving the same error.

Binding the parameters using `text` and `bindparams` of sqlalchemy

```
query = text(USER_ID_QUERY).bindparams(user_id=user_id)
```

Could someone please help me in highlighting what is wrong here or what can be done to resolve these painfull issues?

Comment: Please edit your question and add definition/content of `USER_ID_QUERY`

Comment: Added sample query

Comment: String formatting is indeed insecure. See here how to do it correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324366/150978 Looks in the end very similar but works a bit different and is thus secure.